# tkinter window won't close after .destroy()

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

I am trying t get a tkinter window to close upon xxx.destroy().  The window seems to persist until the program ends.  I cannot understand why xxx.destroy() does't close the tkinter window.  I am on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, Python 3.7.1, and tkinter 8.6.

The Python code is:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
#  https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/
# from set_path import set_path
# set_path ()
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import sys
print(f'The version of Python is {sys.version}')
print (f'The version of tkinter is {tk.TkVersion}')
"""         """
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('tkinter .destroy() Demo')
        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="OK", command = self.button_example_1)       
        self.button.pack(expand=True, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    
    def button_example_1(self):
        self.destroy()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The window (root) should be destroyed by now")
"""         """
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    print ("returned from mainloop(); pausing")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("end pause")
"""         """
```

Comment: can't reproduce the problem, upon pressing the button the window closes (Windows 8.1, Python 3.8.2, tkinter 8.6)

Comment: I can't reproduce on OSX either. I don't see any reason why this would hang.

Comment: Brian - when I run it on OSX the tkinter window doesn't close until the 'print ("end pause")' statement runs.  Are you certain the tkinter window closes upon pressing the button?

Comment: This code worked when I updated to Python 3.8.2 on OSX,  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem when running the code from Qt console and IPython. However, the created window closes properly when running the code from the terminal ('python code.py').